# Fading dynamically loaded content in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a simple website and I am trying to set up a simple slide show that fades from one image to another.  The way I have it set up currently it will load all the images from a folder into the html (dynamically) using JQuery.

I have it so that it get's the list of image names (through php) and then just add's the html for each image (images is just an array of the names of each image):

```
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    $('#slideshow').append('<img id="\"slide' + i + '\"" src="animations/' + images[i] + '" style=\"display: none;\"/>');
}
```

It then calls this method which should begin (and continue) to cycle through them.  I got it working without the dynamically loaded images, but seeing as you can't use .css or .fadeIn with dynamic content I am stuck

```
function countDown() {
    setTimeout(countDown, 4000);
    lastSlideNum = count;
    count++;
    if(count > images.length)
        count = 0;
    currentSlideNum = count;

    //This next part never gets called  because it can't access the dynamically created img
    $("#slide" + lastSlideNum).fadeOut('slow', function() { 
        $(this).css("display", "none");
        $("#slide" + currentSlideNum).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

I realize it probably isn't pretty or the easiest way of doing things, but any advice on this would help greatly.  Keep in mind I'm pretty new to JQuery, so if there is a much easier way about this please let me know.

TL;DR:
Any work around for fading in and out dynamically loaded content?

Comment: wrap in `document ready` and look into `.on()`

Comment: It is wrapped in a document ready, I just didn't put all the code here.  And I thought the .on() was for the same types of things as .live(), such as clicking and things like that.  Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/QAa7a/

The idea is querying using $("#slideshow img:nth-child(" + lastSlideNum + ")"):

```
function countDown() {
    setTimeout(countDown, 4000);
    lastSlideNum = count + 1;
    count++;
    if(count >= images.length)
        count = 0;
    currentSlideNum = count + 1;

    //This next part never gets called  because it can't access the dynamically created img
    console.log(lastSlideNum + "?" + $("#slide" + lastSlideNum).length);
    $("#slideshow img:nth-child(" + lastSlideNum + ")").fadeOut('slow', function() { 
        $(this).css("display", "none");
        $("#slideshow img:nth-child(" + currentSlideNum + ")").fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

Check this link in case you don't familiar with nth-child selector: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!  I just copy pasted it for now, but I will be sure to look into this method when I get the chance.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing things in a very jQuery way with all the index numbers and such.  You can simplify greatly here.  There is no reason you can't access elements that have been dynamically added to the DOM with jQuery.

```
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    $('#slideshow').append('<img class="rotating_image" src="animations/' + images[i] + '" style="display: none;"/>');
}

var slide_interval = 4000;
continue = true;
while (continue === true) {
    $('.rotating_image').each( function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow').delay(slide_interval).fadeOut('slow');
    });
}
```